# Where can I get a data set containing road length,road type(both) of Delhi,India

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I have a dataset that contains latitude, longitude(one pair) and road type of each road of a road network.

But I need road length for each road. So how can I get it?

Comment: Hi @Geethanjai Geethu, just to be abundantly clear, by "one pair" do you mean you only have a point (x1, y1) for each road or a pair of points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)?

Comment: I removed the tags `data.gov,` `openstreetmap` and `traffic` because they aren't relevant to your question *as it's currently written*. If you meant for your question to relate to those tags, please use the [edit] link to update your question.

Comment: @sboysel-I have only one point for each road. Btw I got dataset , thank you for answering.